# Returning words before different specific characters

Tags: c#

I have the following code that gets the word before the `comma`.

```
static string GetString(string input)
{
    try
    {
        return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(','));
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Example:

> Input: Lennon, John
>
> Result: Lennon

The problem is I need to specify multiple characters; not just the `comma`.

For example: I need to get all words before the following: `,([!`

How do I do this?

Comment: can you be more specific ? for ex. if input is `Lennon ! John, Jack` what should be the output?

Comment: Empty catch... Can't believe this still happens!

Comment: @Selman22 thanks! Basically, I am looking for the first word but I need to be able to specify the index character. In your example, I would be only interested in Lennon. The data I am working with contained only one character in each string. It is either one or the other but not both as you example.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy okey then `IndexOfAny` is the right choice.I just wanted to make sure

Comment: @UweKeim and worst of all it is used to control the code flow where a simple if could avoid an expensive exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IndexOfAny` instead, which allows you specify an array of characters:

```
return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOfAny(new[] { ',', '(', '[', '!' }));
```

I'd also suggest that you don't need the `try / catch` block, as that's used to catch exceptions, and this isn't really an "exceptional" situation.

```
var index = input.IndexOfAny(new[] { ',', '(', '[', '!' });

return index > -1 ? input.Substring(0, index) : string.Empty;
```

Comment: I like this because it does not use the `Try Catch`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [string.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, I would prefer to add a safety net in your method and do not rely on the exception to drive the code flow

```
static string GetString(string input)
{
     int pos = input.IndexOfAny(new char[] {',','(', '[', '!'});
     return (pos >= 0 ? input.Substring(0, pos) : string.Empty;
}
```

Using exceptions to control the code flow is a bad practice. An exception is really costly in terms of performance. In your case I really suggest to split the code in two lines and test the result returning the desidered output if the characters are not present at all.

Just to demonstrate the difference in a worst case scenario:

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "test";
    string result;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for(int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
        result = GetString(input);

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for(int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
        result = GetString2(input);

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

string GetString(string input)
{
     int pos = input.IndexOfAny(new char[] {',','(', '[', '!'});
     return (pos >= 0 ? input.Substring(0, pos) : string.Empty);
}

string GetString2(string input)
{
    try
    {
       return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOfAny(new [] { ',', '(', '[', '!' }));
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The first loop is executed 1 million times in 241 milliseconds, the second loop is executed one hundred thousand times in 5300 milliseconds (On my machine, YMMV)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) which is like `IndexOf` but takes an array of characters to match:

```
static string GetString(string input)
{
    try
    {
       return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOfAny(new [] { ',', '(', '[', '!' }));
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use regex or string.Split. I would prefer to use string.split. regex would be oversized.

The code would look like: 
string[] inputSplit = input.Split(new [] {",", "(", "[", "!"}, StringSplitOptions.None);